# Is it possible to pass a nav widget in the Wordpress (Sidebar) new $args?

Tags: php, wordpress, navigation, widget, args

I've spent some time searching, but I haven't really found anything concrete in regards to passing new [`$args`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/) to a navigation widget. I did stumble across [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/145094/override-custom-menu-widget). However, I think the answer is a little overkill for what I'm trying to achieve.

*To sum up the linked post it basically goes on to show how you could accomplish what I need, but only if an entirely new widget is created.*

---

> Specifically, I'm looking to either merge or overwrite the following
>   `$args` exclusively for a menu widget placed within a Wordpress sidebar;

```
wp_nav_menu( array $args = array(
   'menu'              => "header-quicklinks",
   'menu_id'           => "quicklinks",
   'theme_location'    => "sidebar-header"
) );
```

If possible I would like to pass the ID of the widget, in my case `nav_menu-6`; to the function and have the `$args` only apply to that menu specifically, this way I can touch up the code to target other menus should I have the requirement.

Currently tinkering with the following;

```
function widget_nav_args($args){
  $menu = $args['menu'];
  if($menu->term_id === "menu-quick-links") { // < Error: non-object.
     return array_merge( $args, array(
            'menu_class' => 'TESTING', // for testing.
            // More settings here ... 
     ) );
  }
  return $args;
}
add_filter('widget_nav_menu_args', 'widget_nav_args');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are nearly there. The `widget_nav_menu_args` filter accepts more parameters than just the `$args` for the nav. You want to look at the widget arguments which is the 3rd paremeter. It would look something like this:

```
function widget_nav_args( $nav_menu_args, $nav_menu, $args, $instance){ // <- notice extra params..

    if( $args['id'] === 'sidebarheader' ) { // < This is where we check if it's the right widget
      return array_merge( $nav_menu_args, array(
          'menu_class' => 'TESTING', // for testing.
          // More settings here ... 
     ) );
  }

  return $nav_menu_args;
}

add_filter('widget_nav_menu_args', 'widget_nav_args', 10, 4);
```

Notice I had to explicitly say how many arguments to pass to my filter function. Be sure to read through the documentation in the [WP Codex here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/widget_nav_menu_args/).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hey buddy, thanks for your efforts but I had no luck with this, It doesn't appear to be targeting anything at all, any idea why?

Comment: @Beaniie Sorry my bad, I was returning `$args` instead of `$nav_menu_args`. I've edited the code example. (Basically I used the var names in the WP codex, which were different to the var names in your example)

Comment: No worries, I'm still having no luck with this. Would the Id of the Navigation widget be in the `$args` though? I would have thought it wouldn't be as it's not part of the walker but part of the Widget itself?

Comment: @Beaniie The `$args` are the arguments of the current widget, see [WP Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/widget_nav_menu_args/) which includes its `id`. What you need to check is whether `nav_menu-6` is the id you're looking for. Just pop `print_r($args)` in that function so see if it helps..

Comment: `Array ( [widget_id] => nav_menu-6 [widget_name] => Navigation Menu )`, I have a function that prints the ID of the widget in the widget settings just before the update button but to be safe I used `print_r($args)`. All appears to be correct there but I think it's failing on this line, ` return array_merge( $nav_menu_args, array(`.

Comment: @Beaniie I've tested it on a WP site and I'm able to see that it adds the class 'TESTING' to the menu. Are you not seeing that?

Comment: Sadly not,  :( It may be conflicting with something else. but I'm not receiving a error so not sure why it's failing, I'll keep digging into it for the time being.

Comment: Would the fact that it's a custom registered sidebar have an effect here? You know cause an issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189134/discussion-between-dafoxuk-and-beaniie).

Answer (score -2):

```
add_filter('widget_nav_menu_args', 'my_wp_nav_menu_args');

function my_wp_nav_menu_args($args) {

    if (is_page(2) //Only target page 2 
            && $args['theme_location'] === 'primary') { // Check and only target the primary menu
        $args['menu'] = 'Menu for Profile';
    }
    return $args;
}
```

sample arguments are as below.

```
$arguments = array(
    'menu' => '',
    'container' => 'div',
    'container_class' => '',
    'container_id' => '',
    'menu_class' => 'menu',
    'menu_id' => '',
    'echo' => true,
    'fallback_cb' => 'wp_page_menu',
    'before' => '',
    'after' => '',
    'link_before' => '',
    'link_after' => '',
    'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
    'item_spacing' => 'preserve',
    'depth' => 0,
    'walker' => '',
    'theme_location' => ''
);
```